# How to log off all user from ssh client in ssh server?

Tags: ssh, 20.04, sshd

How to log off all user from ssh client in ssh server? not just a particular user, so that i don't have to log off one-by-one from ssh server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this example: Log Everyone Out Of The System](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-command-log-off-all-existing-sessions-accounts/)

- `who` or `w` command – Show who is logged on and what they are doing.
- `pkill` command – Kill user session and forcefully logout of the system.
- `shutdown` command – Arranges for the system to be brought down in a safe way.

Comment: thanks a lot .. :)